# Connect to the internet with static IP, netmask, and DNS addresses

Tags: internet, static-ip

I have installed Ubuntu for the first time and I tried to connect to the internet but generally when I connect to that network in Widnows the IP address must be set manually by specifing the IP, the subnet mask and the DNS. How can I achieve that in Ubuntu so to connect to the internet?

Comment: When you click to "Ask a Question," take the time to read the advice on [how to ask a question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) with emphasis on looking to see if there's already an answer.

Comment: @JohnSGruber Looking at that post, it would seem more a bug report than anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the networks icon on top bar.  Then click on it and then click on Edit Connections...
After that choose which NIC you will use.  After that click it then edit.  Afterword use the IPv4 settings to setup your static codes to connect.

If you are already connected over the connection you will have to reconnect in order to put any changes into effect.

Comment: If configuring a static IP with a relatively intuitive GUI is too complicated, perhaps you should hire someone to implement DHCP with MAC address reservations on your network.